# trying to understand ReflectionClass in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

interface NSerializable
{
    // ...
}

class ParentClass
{
    // test...
}

/**
 * A counter class test
 */
class Counter extends ParentClass implements NSerializable
{
    const START = 0;
    private static $c = Counter::START;
    /**
     * Invoke counter test
     *
     * @access public
     * @return int
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return self::$c++;
    }
}

// Create an instance of the ReflectionClass class
$class = new ReflectionClass('Counter');

// Print out basic information
printf(
    "===> The %s%s%s %s '%s' [extends %s]\n" .
        " declared in %s\n" .
        " lines %d to %d\n" .
        " having the modifiers %d [%s]\n",
    $class->isInternal() ? 'internal' : 'user-defined',
    $class->isAbstract() ? ' abstract' : '',
    $class->isFinal() ? ' final' : '',
    $class->isInterface() ? 'interface' : 'class',
    $class->getName(),
    var_export($class->getParentClass(), 1),
    $class->getFileName(),
    $class->getStartLine(),
    $class->getEndline(),
    $class->getModifiers(),
    implode(' ', Reflection::getModifierNames(
        $class->getModifiers()
    ))
);

// Print documentation comment
printf(
    "---> Documentation:\n %s\n",
    var_export($class->getDocComment(), 1)
);

// Print which interfaces are implemented by this class
printf(
    "---> Implements:\n %s\n",
    var_export($class->getInterfaces(), 1)
);

// Print class constants
printf(
    "---> Constants: %s\n",
    var_export($class->getConstants(), 1)
);

// Print class properties
printf(
    "---> Properties: %s\n",
    var_export($class->getProperties(), 1)
);

// Print class methods
printf(
    "---> Methods: %s\n",
    var_export($class->getMethods(), 1)
);

// If this class is instantiable, create an instance
if ($class->isInstantiable()) {
    $counter = $class->newInstance();
    echo '---> $counter is instance? ';
    echo $class->isInstance($counter) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    echo "\n---> new ParentClass() is instance? ";
    echo $class->isInstance(new ParentClass()) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

Questions:

1. `var_export($class->getParentClass(), 1)`, output is:
   ===> The user-defined class 'Counter' [extends ReflectionClass::__set_state(array( 'name' => 'ParentClass', ))]... `var_export($class->getParentClass())`, output is: ReflectionClass::__set_state(array( 'name' => 'ParentClass', ))===> The user-defined class 'Counter' [extends ]... why?
2. `$class->getParentClass()`, output is: ReflectionClass::__set_state(array( 'name' => 'ParentClass', )) what does this mean: '__set_state'?
3. `getModifiers()`,`getModifierNames()` what does these two functions actually mean?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: ... and your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers 1. and 2.:

[`$class->getParentClass()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) is actually an object of type `ReflectionClass` not a string.

Replace:

```
var_export($class->getParentClass())
```

by:

```
$class->getParentClass()->getName()
```

---

3 . There is not method `ReflectionClass::getModifierNames()`. I don't know where you got this information from, but if you need it you'll have to write your own. Here comes an example that extends `ReflectionClass` and adds the method:

```
class MyReflectionClass extends ReflectionClass 
{

    /**
     * Returns the modifiers in human readable format
     */
    public function getModifierNames() {
        $m = $this->getModifiers();
        $names = array();
        if($m & self::IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT === self::IS_EXPLICIT_ABSTRACT
        || $m & self::IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT === self::IS_IMPLICIT_ABSTRACT) {
            $names []= 'abstract';
        }
        if($m & self::IS_FINAL === self::IS_FINAL) {
            $names []= 'final';
        }

        return implode(' ', $names);
    }

}
```

Use:

```
abstract class Counter extends Object 
  implements NSerializable
{ // ...
```

or

```
final class Counter extends Object 
  implements NSerializable
{ // ...
```

and

```
$class = new MyReflectionClass('Counter');
```

to test it